# Can the SoundCloud API be accessed from Windows directly (with a python script, say) or must it be an internet application run from a server?

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, apache, soundcloud

I'm looking to put together something that automatically uploads songs to SoundCloud and it would be really easy if I could integrate it with my current project by just executing a python script.

I don't need an Apache server or something along those lines to run it from, do I?

Answer (score 1):

That is possible with Javascript, Python, or ruby (you listed these in the tags, but you can pretty much use anything).

To read more about using the API to upload sounds see [this section of the documentation](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#uploading).

You don't need to run apache you can access the api directly client-side.

[Tool for soundcloud with python.](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python)

[SDK for soundcloud with javascript.](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks)

[Tool for soundcloud with ruby.](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-ruby)